# Can't reach Flask server running in Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, flask

I'm building a Flask + React webapp that runs correctly on my machine. I try to dockerize it. I can build image (*stiko:demo*), docker runs, server starts:

[image]

But when I try to open `https://0.0.0.0:5000/` on my browser, connection fails:

[image]

I've searched for a while now, trying to start from various images, trying to use `ENDPOINT` + `CMD` command, use `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` but still the same issue.

- Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu

RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install python3.9 -y
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app/build
COPY ./build ./

WORKDIR /app/server
COPY ./server ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
RUN pip3 install python-dotenv

ENV APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"

EXPOSE 5000
```

- app.py:

```
import sys
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

from models import User, Project, Image, db
from api import blueprints

app = Flask(__name__,
  static_folder='../build/static',
  template_folder="../build"
)

app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
db.init_app(app)
cors = CORS(app)

# Register the blueprints
for b in blueprints:
  app.register_blueprint(b)

@cross_origin
@app.route('/', defaults={'u_path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:u_path>')
def index(u_path=None):
  return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host=('0.0.0.0'), port=5000, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

- project structure:

```
  build
  |__static
  |__index.html
  |__ ...
  server
  |__app.py
  |__requirements.txt
  |__ ...
  Dockerfile
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just in case someone would be stuck like me, with probably zero network skill:

The Dockerfile and app.py are just fine. But instead of trying to access `https://0.0.0.0:5000/` in browser I should have tried `https://127.0.0.1:5000/` which works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dockerfile` doesn't appear to be starting your flask api. Try adding a CMD to the end.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu

RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install python3.9 -y
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app/build
COPY ./build ./

WORKDIR /app/server
COPY ./server ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
RUN pip3 install python-dotenv

ENV APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Comment: I tried, still the same result. In my first image, you can see that ran `python3 app.py` from the container directly.